# Htmlunit Skipping Page With Button Click

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, htmlunit

I have a program written with Htmlunit to return information from several pages on a website. The issue is, while the first two pages return fine, every other page is then returned (pages 1, 2, 4, 6, etc are returned). I believe all the variables I reference are correct, so I am not sure whether the issue is with the server communicating with the program, or another issue. My code is:

```
  public static void scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(s);
    originalHtml = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    obtainInformation();
    originalHtml = "";

    //////code below returns page 2 as expected////

    final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue(">");
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    try {
      synchronized (page2) {
        page2.wait(5000);
      }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
      System.out.println("error");
    }
    originalHtml = originalHtml + page2.refresh().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    obtainInformation();
    originalHtml = "";


    /////// code below returns page 4, instead of page 3/////

    final HtmlForm form2 = page2.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlSubmitInput button2 = form2.getInputByValue(">");
    final HtmlPage page3 = button2.click();
    try {
      synchronized (page3) {
        page3.wait(5000);
      }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
      System.out.println("error");
    }
    originalHtml = originalHtml + page3.refresh().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    obtainInformation();
}
```

The only issue I can think of is that when page.refresh() is run it essentially double clicks the button, but without the page.refresh() the information on the 1st page is just returned 3 times. Also, s refers to the string of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without taking a look at the page that you're trying to fetch, there are some things that actually smell odd in your code.

1. You have copy/pasted code. That is not correct, lead to hard to follow code and is very error prone. Make sure you modularize your code so that you don't have to repeat it for each page.
2. It is not clear what you're doing with the `originalHtml` variable. It seems it is a static variable that you only write in that method. You don't seem to read it in there so you're probably reading it in the `obtainInformation()` method, in which case it should be used only in that method. Not to mention you're assigning it the value `""` and then the value of the page which makes the assignment of `""` unnecessary.
3. I don't see any reason to operate on the raw Html returned by HtmlUnit rather than its XML representation. You should replace `page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()` with `page.asXml()`. Of course, if you really need to save the raw Html of the page to a file, then leave it as it is.
4. I don't see any reason to perform a `refresh()` there. You get `page2` and wait 5 seconds (blindly assuming that the page as the new content ready to operate on it). Then, instead of operating on `page2` you refresh it and get the content of the new page. This might be the cause of you getting the first page properly and the rest spaced by 2.

Those are just some general comments that should help you. They will not necessarily fix the issue but should considerably improve your code.

Comment: The refresh was needed for some, and not needed for others. I believe something is up with the website causing each iteration to need different code.